# How does clojure's syntax-quote work?

Tags: clojure

Various special characters in clojure are abbreviations for things

`(quote (a b))` is the same as `'(a b)`

as you can see by evaluating:

```
user> ''(a b)
(quote (a b))
```

This seems to be syntax as abbreviation, which strikes me as a fine idea.

But the syntax-quote, ` , seems special. I can't think what would be equivalent to

```
`(a b)
```

I would have guessed something like `(syntax-quote (a b))` , but it doesn't work, and if I've just guessed wrong, I can't find out what it's really called.

```
user> '`(a b)
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote user/a)) (clojure.core/list (quote user/b))))
```

Is a bit mystifying.

Presumably the reader's doing something special, maybe because it needs to know the namespaces?

Interestingly, the special syntax used in the syntax-quote does work as I expected:

```
user> '~a
(clojure.core/unquote a)
user> '~@a
(clojure.core/unquote-splicing a)
user> '~'a
(clojure.core/unquote (quote a))
```

except for this one:

```
user> 'a#
a#
```

Which I would have thought produced something like `(unquote (gensym "a"))`

I do realise that I'm being a bit feeble here, and should just go and read the code. If no-one fancies explaining what's going on or giving a reference, can anyone give me a hint about how to find the relevant code and what to look for?

Comment: There's a really good article for this https://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't think there's a syntax-quote equivalent of the `quote` function.

The Clojure reader is (currently) written in Java.  The `SyntaxQuoteReader` class in `src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java` in the Clojure source is probably what you'll want to read.  It seems rather complex.  You can see it building lists like `(seq (concat ...))` there.

```
                ret = RT.list(SEQ, RT.cons(CONCAT, sqExpandList(seq)));
```

It's common for the reader not to return straightforward Clojure code, but rather do the right thing in Java-land immediately.  For example `'[1 2 3]` doesn't yield the Clojure code `(vector 1 2 3)`.  Maybe it could work that way somehow, but it doesn't.  The reader just creates and returns the vector object itself.

Likewise, the `SyntaxQuoteReader` does some magic in Java immediately to resolve symbol namespaces and create gensyms itself and it returns some mangled and complicated-looking Clojure code that does the right thing, but isn't necessarily easy for a human to read.  Whether it's like this because it has to be, or because it's easier to do it this way in Java, or for performance or some other reason, I don't know.  Likewise I don't know if `quasiquote` could exist as a plain macro/special form in Clojure and doesn't, or if it couldn't exist at all.  I don't see why it couldn't though.

`WrappingReader` in the same file is the class that handles `'` (plain old `quote`).  You can see that it just wraps whatever you pass it in a list containing the symbol `quote` plus your argument.  It's much simpler.  Note that this class also handles `@`, so that `'@foo` does return `(deref foo)`.

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/6d0c5f7e37909055) might shed some more light.

### Edit

Here's a proof-of-concept `quasiquote` macro.  Note that this code is relying upon and abusing Clojure internals in a horrible way.  Please don't use this for anything.

```
user> (defmacro quasiquote [x]
        (let [m (.getDeclaredMethod clojure.lang.LispReader$SyntaxQuoteReader 
                                    "syntaxQuote" 
                                    (into-array [Object]))]
          (.setAccessible m true)
          (.invoke m nil (into-array [x]))))
#'user/quasiquote
user> (let [x 123] `(x 'x ~x))
(user/x (quote user/x) 123)
user> (let [x 123] (quasiquote (x 'x ~x)))
(user/x (quote user/x) 123)
```

Comment: That is deep black magic! What a hack! I don't have any more upvotes to give you, but that's cool.

Comment: One thing to note about the quasiquote macro is to add something like `(push-thread-bindings {(get-static-field clojure.lang.LispReader 'GENSYM_ENV) {}})` before the invoke call if you need support for implicit gensyms.

Comment: I forgot that you then must wrap the expression into a try...finally and call pop-thread-bindings in the finally clause to do that cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

hiredman has implemented a fully clojure-based version of [syntax-quote](https://github.com/hiredman/clojure/blob/readerII/src/clj/clojure/reader.clj#L367). Not for the faint of heart, but a good proof of concept.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a great grasp of the macro syntax to start with so there is not too much I can add.

there is a bit of coverage on the [programming clojure forums](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/91/topics/2740). 
and you may at your leasure read the [code here](http://github.com/hiredman/clojure/blob/f4a75e9bf35a5eff2c4dec85b36d37f59d04cd59/src/clj/clojure/reader.clj) check out line 352

Comment: Thanks Arthur, those are really handy.