# Quoting Confusion

Tags: clojure

Why does this series of clojure commands return false and not true? What is the difference between the result of statement 1 "C" and 2 "(quote C)"?

```
; SLIME 2009-03-04
user> ('A 'B 'C)
C
user> (last '('A 'B 'C))
(quote C)
user> (= ('A 'B 'C) (last '('A 'B 'C)))
false
```

This question is somewhat similar to [How does clojure's syntax-quote work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704372/how-does-clojures-syntax-quote-work)

Comment: Did you mean "Quoting Confujon"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Clojure (and other Lisps) the `'` is a shortcut for the form `(quote ...)`. So when Clojure sees this:

```
('A 'B 'C)
```

which is "translated" by the reader into:

```
((quote A) (quote B) (quote C))
```

Each of those quote forms evaluates to a symbol, so `(quote A)` evaluates to the symbol named A. In Clojure, symbols are functions and can be applied, so `((quote A) (quote B) (quote C))` is actually a function call. From the docs:

"Symbols, just like Keywords, implement IFn for invoke() of one argument (a map) with an optional second argument (a default value). For example ('mysym my-hash-map :none) means the same as (get my-hash-map 'mysym :none)."

So what happens is that `C` is the default value and that's why it's returned.

Meanwhile, this

```
'('A 'B 'C)
```

is translated by the reader into

```
(quote ((quote A) (quote B) (quote C)))
```

Which is actually a list of three elements, each of which is a list of two elements, the symbol `quote` and another symbol (in this case `A`, `B`, `C`).

So, `(last '('A 'B 'C))` is actually `(quote C)`. That's the difference between those two results, `C` is the symbol with the name C while `(quote C)` is a list of two elements.

You can confirm this:

```
user=> (class ('A 'B 'C))
clojure.lang.Symbol
user=> (class (last '('A 'B 'C)))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=>
```

Hope that's clear!

Answer (score 1):

('x 'y) is very unusual, for just this reason. Usually you want '(x y), which is a list of the literal symbols x and y. If you quote TWICE with '('x 'y), you get a list with (quote x)  instead: the literal symbol quote, followed by the literal symbol x.