# How to invoke syntax-quote without using the backtick character?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, for quote I can use either the tick character or `quote`:

```
user=> '(+ 2 2)
(+ 2 2)
user=> (quote (+ 2 2))
(+ 2 2)
```

However for syntax-quote I can seemingly only use the backtick operator:

```
user=> `(+ 2 2)
(clojure.core/+ 2 2)
user=> (syntax-quote (+ 2 2))

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: syntax-quote in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

Is there a way to invoke syntax-quote without using the backtick character?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [clojure.tools.reader](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader)

```
(require '[clojure.tools.reader :as r])
-> nil

(r/syntax-quote +)
-> clojure.core/+
```

Answer (score 1):

This questions has largely been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704372/how-does-clojures-syntax-quote-work). Since then, the [clojure-in-clojure](https://github.com/clojure/tools.analyzer.jvm) analyzer was created so you can get something somewhat similar to a syntax quote using:

```
(use '[clojure.tools.analyzer.passes.jvm.emit-form :only [emit-form]]
 '[clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm :only [analyze]])

(emit-form (analyze '(+ 2 2)))
;-> (clojure.lang.Numbers/add 2 2)
```

As you can see, the function is actually resolved right down to the Java code that will execute rather than just resolving the namespace of the symbol.